# How do I remove indexes in findall of cakephp

Tags: ajax, cakephp-2.0

I have the following code:

```
$s= $this->ShowFare->find('all');

Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [ShowFare] => Array
            (
                [id] => 21
                [press_release_id] => 14
                [category] => 0
                [title] => pr
                [image_name] => 1486719733.jpg
                [crop_image] => 1486719729.jpg
                [is_default] => 0
                [is_active] => 0
                [created] => 2017-02-10 09:42:13
                [created_by] => 0
                [modified] => 2017-02-10 09:42:13
                [modified_by] => 0
                [deleted] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [deleted_by] => 0
            )

        [PressRelease] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [title] => 
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ShowFare] => Array
            (
                [id] => 22
                [press_release_id] => 7
                [category] => 0
                [title] => abcd
                [image_name] => 1486721484.jpg
                [crop_image] => 1486721481.jpg
                [is_default] => 0
                [is_active] => 0
                [created] => 2017-02-10 10:11:24
                [created_by] => 0
                [modified] => 2017-02-10 10:11:24
                [modified_by] => 0
                [deleted] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [deleted_by] => 0
            )

        [PressRelease] => Array
            (
                [id] => 7
                [title] => ht48 hours, 04 March 2016
            )

    )

 )
```

I want the above results in following format:

```
Array
 (
   Array
     (
        [ShowFare] => Array
            (
                [id] => 21
                [press_release_id] => 14
                [category] => 0
                [title] => pr
                [image_name] => 1486719733.jpg
                [crop_image] => 1486719729.jpg
                [is_default] => 0
                [is_active] => 0
                [created] => 2017-02-10 09:42:13
                [created_by] => 0
                [modified] => 2017-02-10 09:42:13
                [modified_by] => 0
                [deleted] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [deleted_by] => 0
            )

        [PressRelease] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [title] => 
            )

    )

Array
    (
        [ShowFare] => Array
            (
                [id] => 22
                [press_release_id] => 7
                [category] => 0
                [title] => abcd
                [image_name] => 1486721484.jpg
                [crop_image] => 1486721481.jpg
                [is_default] => 0
                [is_active] => 0
                [created] => 2017-02-10 10:11:24
                [created_by] => 0
                [modified] => 2017-02-10 10:11:24
                [modified_by] => 0
                [deleted] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [deleted_by] => 0
            )

        [PressRelease] => Array
            (
                [id] => 7
                [title] => ht48 hours, 04 March 2016
            )

      )

  )
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you can simply use foreach loop if you want to get inner data..

Comment: got it dude! Thanks!!